# using StringCchPrintf to build string from substring

Tags: c++, strsafe

I'm trying to build a string from a substring which comes from an error message:

```
// the error message
const char* error_msg = e.what();

size_t const cchDest = 100;
TCHAR pszDest[cchDest]; 

LPCTSTR pszFormat = TEXT("%s %s");
TCHAR* pszTxt = TEXT("The error is: ");

HRESULT hr = StringCchPrintf(pszDest, cchDest, pszFormat, pszTxt, error_msg );
```

I was hoping that the second `%s` will be replaced with the value of `error_msg`, however the output is:

`The error is: ☐☐a`

How do I have to modify above code so that the substring shows up?

**EDIT1**
I've also tried the following, but all I get is a box again.

```
TCHAR* pszTxt = TEXT("The error is: %c", error_msg );
HRESULT hr = StringCchPrintf(pszDest, cchDest, pszTxt);
```

Comment: @hmjd well, 'bla bla' is only an example here. Imagine that this will be an error message that's coming from some variable.

Comment: @memyself Don't post code that *approximates* to your problem, post code that accurately reflects your problem. Otherwise you only get an approximate answer.

Comment: @john ok, sorry. I've modified the original posting to reflect the true problem.

Comment: Try replacing "%s %s" with "%s %hs", your second string is char not THCAR, so there is no guarantee that %s is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
LPCTSTR pszFormat = TEXT("%s %hs");
TCHAR* pszTxt = TEXT("The error is: ");

HRESULT hr = StringCchPrintf(pszDest, cchDest, pszFormat, pszTxt, error_msg);
```